# Does anyone know how to get SonarQube to analyze CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript, agile, sonarqube

I've recently moved into a position which is polyglot and some team members use CoffeeScript and I want to be able to run it through SonarQube for quality analysis and issue identification. Is there a way to get the JavaScript plugin to parse/handle CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoffeeScript is  not supported by the JS plugin. And AFAIK, there's currently no SQ CoffeeScript plugin out there.

Comment: Anyone interested in helping to make a CoffeeScript module for SonarQube? Send me a message if so and we'll fire up a GitHub repo!

Comment: Hey I am just wondering @infosec812 , did you ever create a repo or get anywhere with testing coffeescript in SQ?

Comment: @Jaddie not yet. Time constraints and all it has been pretty hectic.